# UIAlertView Strange Behaviour with Shortcut Control center

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uialertview, control-center

i am facing the problem with the UIAlertview behaviour,i Know when alertview is raised except the external controls all the controls will get inactive.

```
 My app on of the functionality will work only on airplain mode,My client wanted to use the control center to enable airplain mode.In my appUntil unless user activating the airplain mode Alertview will keep raise.
```

But for the first Alert display i am unable to open the shortcut control center.If i hit okey without activation then app waill raise same alert again.Then i can able to open Shortcut control center. I am wondering with this behaviour.

If any one faced this kind o behaviour,please let me know,How can i resolve this.